# Spring Boot for older version of java

Tags: spring-boot

I am looking to create a new web application using spring boot. Unfortunately my server is fairly locked down in terms of the technology stack. It has java 5 installed on it.

Can anyone tell me whether spring boot can run on java 1.5 and what version?

thanks

Comment: Spring boot requires at least `java6` .i recommend to upgrade java version

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Spring Boot 2.0, the requirement is Java 8 as a minimum version.

From the [Spring Boot 2.0 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes) :

> Spring Boot 2.0 requires **Java 8 as a minimum version**. Many existing
>   APIs have been updated **to take advantage of Java 8 features** such as:
>   default methods on interfaces, functional callbacks, and new APIs such
>   as javax.time. If you are currently using Java 7 or earlier, you’ll
>   need to upgrade your JDK before you can develop Spring Boot 2.0
>   applications.

Comment: Thanks for nice answering.

Answer (score 8):

Since Spring boot 1.0.0, the minimal requirement to run a Spring boot application has been Java 6. This can also be found in [the reference guide of Spring boot 1.0.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installing-spring-boot):

> Spring Boot can be used with “classic” Java development tools or installed as a command line tool. Regardless, you will need Java SDK v1.6 or higher.

Support for older Java versions has been dropped throughout releases, with Spring boot 1.3 moving to Java 7 as a baseline (still possible to use Java 6 [with additional configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6)) and Spring boot 2.x moving to Java 8 as a baseline. Additionally to what the documentation says, none of the Spring boot 1.x versions [support Java 9 or higher](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10646#issuecomment-336789642).

Summarized:

- 1.0.0: Support from Java 6 - 8
- 1.3.0: Support from Java 7 - 8, additional configuration for Java 6 required
- 2.0.0: Support from Java 8 - ...

So, the answer is that it's not possible to run in Java 5.